# How do I configure SDL_image to use a version of SDL in a peer directory?

Tags: sdl-2, configure, sdl-image

I have built SDL in a folder `~/project/extra/SDL/` and I'm trying to build SDL_image in `~project/extra/SDL_image`. SDL is *not* installed, the project is statically linking to the `~/project/extra/SDL/build/.libs/*.a` library.

How do I configure SDL_image to build with built version of SDL?

`./configure --with-sdl-prefix=../SDL/build/.libs --with-sdl-exec-prefix=../SDL/build` is not workin.

Answer (score 2):

Lean on SDL's [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) tooling to help it find itself in the non-system location:

```
# install SDL2
cd /tmp/SDL2-2.0.10
./configure --prefix=/tmp/sdl-local
make install

# install SDL2_image
cd /tmp/SDL2_image-2.0.5/
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/tmp/sdl-local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure --prefix=/tmp/sdl-local
make install
```

Comment: I can’t install SDL. I just want to use the compiled lib from the peer directory.

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked for me. @Justin808 you probably have solved this or moved on, but the answer does not actually "install" SDL, but rather compiles and links it into a temporary location (/tmp/sdl-local) - you can then use the built files for further compilation/linking